# JDBC Datasources implemented by app servers

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am learning about datasources and I think I am beginning to understand it but this paragraph I don't get.

From what I know now the database vendors such as MySQL and PostgreSQL write their own implementations of the different DataSource interfaces. Now, shouldn't that be sufficient? What does it mean by the app server should provide a DataSource implementation? What is the reason for doing so?

> PostgreSQL implementation of ConnectionPoolDataSource. The app server
>   or middleware vendor should provide a DataSource implementation that
>   takes advantage of this ConnectionPoolDataSource. If not, you can use
>   the PostgreSQL implementation known as PoolingDataSource, but that
>   should only be used if your server or middleware vendor does not
>   provide their own. Why? The server may want to reuse the same
>   Connection across all EJBs requesting a Connection within the same
>   Transaction, or provide other similar advanced features.

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the webapp DataSource will delegate to the PostgreSQL implementation.  This allows monitoring and other features in the webapp, which wouldn't be available if you manage your own datasources.

Comment: The most prominent such feature is pooling, i think. When you ask a 'real' `DataSource` for a `Connection`, it makes you a new one. When you ask an app server's `DataSource` for a connection, it gets it from a pool of ready-made connections. Similarly, when you close the `Connection`, it doesn't really close it, it just puts it back in the pool. This cuts down on the cost of creating new connections, and improves performance.

Comment: @TomAnderson But PostgreSQL already have an implementation for connection pooling?

Comment: That's one of the features.  You could get the pooling benefit by managing your own pool (Using PoolingDataSource or a third party pool like Apache's).  However if you use the app server's pool, a single config can be shared across different webapplications in a single appserver for example.  Also, your app wouldn't need to have access to the connection info or credentials, which is good security wise.

Comment: @AndresOlarte Alright. So the app server doesn't actually have the logic for the pooling/distributed transaction support, but it manages it and delegates to the datasource implemented by a DBMS vendor, but with the added benefit of letting the app server manage it?

Comment: Not exactly.  The app server does contain the pooling logic, and will use this to allow pooling of drivers that don't have their own pooling logic.  In other cases, it might reuse the pooling logic provided by the driver, but this would depend on how the app server was implemented.  At the end of the day, the app server will transparently provide you the features, for any driver, regardless of whether that driver has it already or not. Something like PoolingDataSource is useful for example if you are running outside of an appserver (Swing application for example).

Comment: @Andy: PostgreSQL's `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` *does not* provide pooling. What it provides are some hooks (defined in [`ConnectionPoolDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html)) which an app server can use to implement pooling of connections from that source.

Comment: Which, of course, is exactly what it says in the passage from the documentation which you quote. Your question literally contains its own answer.

Comment: @TomAnderson I do not,understand how it just provides some hooks, wheremdo you read/understand that? Whatndo the hooks do?

Comment: @Andy: `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` implements `ConnectionPoolDataSource`. If you read the javadoc for that, you will see that it returns instances of `PooledConnection`. If you read the javadoc for that, it explains. It's simply a matter of reading docs and following links.

Comment: @TomAnderson Thank you for helping me:
So the app server have a pool of PooledConnections and when you want a connection you get a connection from one of these objects. Then when you call close() on the connection, the app server (?) have registered as a event listener for ConnectionEvents and it will return the PooledConnection object (or mark it) as beeing free again insted of closing the underlying connection? So the interface ConnectionPoolDataSource is just ensuring that you are getting PooledConnections which have all these hooks etc?

Comment: Although sometimes, the app server won't give you the `PooledConnection`, it will wrap it in another class of its own, to have more control. In that case, it may not actually need to use `PooledConnection`. App servers can also use this approach to pool connections to databases which don't have a `ConnectionPoolDataSource`, only a normal `DataSource`.

Comment: @TomAnderson One thing though that cause some trouble with my understanding. You declare a reference of type DataSource in your code right. However if the server creates an instance of a class that implement the ConnectionPoolDataSource, then why can you assign it to a DataSource reference? And why can you call getConnection instead of getPooledConnection?

Comment: @Andy: The server doesn't give you the `ConnectionPoolDataSource`, it will give you its own wrapper implementation of `DataSource`. That wrapper will contain a connection pool which uses the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` to create connections. The wrapper is what is calling `ConnectionPoolDataSource#getPooledConnection` (and also `PooledConnection#getConnection`).

Comment: @TomAnderson Just one more thing: PostgreSQL for instance have `PoolingDataSource` that you could use if you are not on an app server etc it looks. Then the same things applies? In this case it is the driver that acts as a datasource which internally do pooling etc but connections are exposed through the data source interface?